# Natural Join between two files in unix using AWK, Join etc

Tags: linux, unix, join, awk

File_a

```
1 MIR6859-1 2340    DDX11L1 3222
2 MIR6859-1 4860    WASH7P  7074
3 WASH7P    326 MIR1302-2   670
4 FAM138A   15  MIR1302-2   5730
8 LOC729737 7270    OR4F5   64205
9 LOC729737 3070    OR4F5   68405
10 LOC729737    88330   LOC100132287    94996
11 LOC100132287 86996   LOC729737   96330
12 LOC100132287 80196   LOC729737   103130
13 LOC100132287 72396   LOC729737   110930
14 LOC100132287 61196   LOC729737   122130
15 LOC100132287 56596   LOC729737   126730
```

File_b

```
10 LOC7 883
15 TYUI 678 
8 LOC123 764
40 QWER 456
8 LOC125 783
```

and expected output is

```
1 MIR6859-1 2340    DDX11L1 3222
2 MIR6859-1 4860    WASH7P  7074
3 WASH7P    326 MIR1302-2   670
4 FAM138A   15  MIR1302-2   5730
8 LOC729737 7270    OR4F5   64205  LOC123 764  LOC125 783
9 LOC729737 3070    OR4F5   68405
10 LOC729737    88330   LOC100132287    94996 LOC7  883
11 LOC100132287 86996   LOC729737   96330
12 LOC100132287 80196   LOC729737   103130
13 LOC100132287 72396   LOC729737   110930
14 LOC100132287 61196   LOC729737   122130
15 LOC100132287 56596   LOC729737   126730 TYUI 678
40 QWER 456
```

So basically this is a Natural Join based on the equality of the first column in both files.

I tried various commands after searching the web -

```
join -a1 file_a file_b
```

and

```
paste file_a file_b
```

but not getting desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR == FNR{ a[$1] = ($1 in a? a[$1] OFS : "")$2 OFS $3; next }
     $1 in a{ $0 = $0 OFS a[$1]; delete a[$1] }1;
     END{ for (i in a) print i, a[i] }' file_b file_a
```

The output:

```
1 MIR6859-1 2340    DDX11L1 3222
2 MIR6859-1 4860    WASH7P  7074
3 WASH7P    326 MIR1302-2   670
4 FAM138A   15  MIR1302-2   5730
8 LOC729737 7270    OR4F5   64205 LOC123 764 LOC125 783
9 LOC729737 3070    OR4F5   68405
10 LOC729737    88330   LOC100132287    94996 LOC7 883
11 LOC100132287 86996   LOC729737   96330
12 LOC100132287 80196   LOC729737   103130
13 LOC100132287 72396   LOC729737   110930
14 LOC100132287 61196   LOC729737   122130
15 LOC100132287 56596   LOC729737   126730 TYUI 678
40 QWER 456
```

Comment: Hello @RomanPerekhrest I am studying your AWK program. It is wicked cool. I think that I understand everything, except the "1" at the end of the second line of your program. What is that doing?

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you on same too.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{val=$1;$1="";sub(/^ +/,"");a[val]=a[val]?a[val] OFS $0:$0;next} {print $0,a[$1]}' FIle_b  FIle_a
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  val=$1;
  $1="";
  sub(/^ +/,"");
  a[val]=a[val]?a[val] OFS $0:$0;
  next}
{
  print $0,a[$1]}
' FIle_b  FIle_a
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation of code too here.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{                         ##FNR==NR is a condition which is TRUE only when first Input_file named FIle_b in this case is being read. Do following in case of this condition is TRUE.
  val=$1;                        ##Creating variable val whose value is first field of the current line.
  $1="";                         ##Nullifying the first field value in current line.
  sub(/^ +/,"");                 ##Using sub out of the box utility of awk here to substitute initial space with NULL here on current line.
  a[val]=a[val]?a[val] OFS $0:$0;##Creating an array named a whose index is variable val and it concatenates its own value in it too. to cover all duplicates in file.
  next}                          ##next is awk out of the box keyword which will skip all further lines from here.
{
  print $0,a[$1]}                ##This print statement will only execute when 2nd Input_file is being read and it prints current line along with that value of araay a whose index is first field of array a.
' FIle_b  FIle_a                 ##Mentioning Input_file(s) here, first Input_file is FIle_b and second Input_file is FIle_a.
```

Comment: @IndraPrakashJha, added explanation too in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add some remarks, to clarify the matter:

1) The join field is duplicated in `file_b`:

```
8 LOC123 764
...
8 LOC125 783
```

In a “real” join in a database, this would produce two lines of output

```
8 LOC729737 7270    OR4F5   64205  LOC123 764  
8 LOC729737 7270    OR4F5   64205  LOC125 783
```

Not the concatenation you want:

```
8 LOC729737 7270    OR4F5   64205 LOC123 764 LOC125 783
```

So, it is misleading to say that you want a join.

2) Even if there were no duplicate lines, it would be a *full outer join* and not a *natural join* because you want all unpaired lines from both sources.

3) `paste` doesn’t work because it only pairs lines with corresponding line numbers in both files, it knows no concept of *join field*.

4) `join` (the unix command) doesn’t work not only because it wants input files sorted by the join field (which would be easy to provide) but also because it does not support full outer joins: the option `-a1` performs a left outer join (include unpairable lines from first source) and the option `-a2` performs a right outer join (include unpairable lines from second source), but using the two options together requires the further option `--nocheck-order` and produces something which is not a full outer join.

5) That said, I am also providing an `awk` solution, which is shorter than the ones provided so far and generates the same output:

```
awk '{k=$1;sub("^"k,"");a[k]=a[k] OFS $0}
     END{for(k in a)print k a[k]|"sort -k1,1n"}' file_a file_b
```

6) If the amount of whitespace between output fields is not significant, you can also use the shorter

```
awk '{k=$1;$1="";a[k]=a[k] $0}
     END{for(k in a)print k a[k]|"sort -k1,1n"}' file_a file_b
```